# How do I get a date formatted as YYY-MM-DD from a cell for using in a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a problem getting a date from a cell in my Google Spreadsheet. I would like to access `A3` in the sheet `Dates`, which holds the date `01/12/2013`, and re-use that as variable `start-date` in the below mentioned script.

```
function fetchMAP28() {
  // our query object
  var query = {
    "optionalArgs": {
      "dimensions": "ga:date",
      "max-results": "50"
    },
    "ids": "",
    "metrics": "ga:users,ga:goal1Completions",
    "start-date":"Here I like the date from the cell",
    "end-date": "yesterday"
  };

  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    query.ids, 
    query['start-date'], 
    query['end-date'], 
    query.metrics, 
    query.optionalArgs
  );

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("dataMAP");
  outputToSpreadsheet(results, sheet); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is. Best is to share a doc and explain what you want to happen. Welcome to Web Applications !!

Comment: This is a good start: http://www.google.com/script/start/

Comment: See link on how to change the date format in GAS: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to get a value from your spreadsheet, and use it in your script?

I have added a couple of lines at the top of your script, and used `startDate` to populate the `query` object:

```
function fetchMAP28() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dates").getRange("A3");
  var startDate = range.getValue();
  // Note the timezone is GMT+1 - you should adjust it to your locale
  var formattedStartDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(startDate), "GMT+1", "yyyy/MM/dd")
  // our query object
  var query = {
    "optionalArgs": {
      "dimensions": "ga:date",
      "max-results": "50"
    },
    "ids": "",
    "metrics": "ga:users,ga:goal1Completions",
    "start-date": formattedStartDate,
    "end-date": "yesterday"
  };

  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(query.ids, query['start-date'], query['end-date'], query.metrics, query.optionalArgs);

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("dataMAP");
  outputToSpreadsheet(results, sheet); 
}
```

The variable `formattedStartDate` contains the string `2013-12-01`.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Last thing: startDate print 2013-11-30T23:00:00.000Z how can I strip it to only have 2013-11-30 without time?

Comment: I would use: `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(startDate), "GMT+1", "yyyy/MM/dd")`, since OP is using GAS.

Comment: Ahh ... of course. So you would need to know the timezone, obviously. Thanks again!

Comment: In my last version, I used `Utilities.formatDate(startDate, ...)` while the current edit says `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(startDate), ...)`. Not sure why you would need to wrap `startDate` in `new Date`, provided you have a date in `A3`.

Comment: Firstly, this is how the usage is described by Google (see comment at OP). Secondly, it will force the input to be seen as a date in all other instances. Since this isn't Stack Overflow, it's better to use it with the `new Date()`wrapped around it.